# Animations don't work after clicking back using AngularJS and UI router

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, animation

I have 2 routes - "main" and "results".

```
$stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "views/main.html"
        })
        .state('results', {
            url: "/results/:searchQuery",
            templateUrl: "views/results.html"
        })
```

In both routes I have included the same directive for search bar. In results route I have a results directive too.

My App controller is attached to body tag.

```
app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope)
{
    if (!angular.isDefined($scope.animations))
    {
        $scope.animations = {};
    }
    $scope.animations.isSmall = false;
});
```

The search partial has a button that sends to the Results route.

```
<button class="btn-search" ui-sref="results({searchQuery: searchQuery})"></button>
```

The results controller sets $scope.animations.isSmall to true if searchQuery is not empty, so that animations start.

```
app.controller("ResultsCtrl", function ($scope, $stateParams, $interval) {
    if ($stateParams.searchQuery && $stateParams.searchQuery != "") {
            $scope.animations.isSmall = true;
    }
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            $scope.animations.isSmall = false;
        });
});
```

The first time I click on the button it takes me to results route and triggers the animations. After that I click back and click the button, it takes me to the results page with no animations.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="main-cont" ng-class="{'small':animations.isSmall, 'big':!animations.isSmall}">
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
section.main .main-cont.small {
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}
section.main .main-cont.big {
    height:500px;
}
```

So, everything works as charm for the first time, and I am sure that I correctly configured the routes and controllers and $scope.animations.isSmall is being updated correctly. I think it doesn't work because of animation-iteration-count. When animation is trigerred, I click back, it resets the page to the initial view. The class triggering animation is not attached to the HTML tag, but it somehow remembers that the animation has already been triggered because of ng-class.

Hopefully I could explain my question. Thanks in advance.